# Bind the date value to UI

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net

I have found the JS for setting the date value to today in a post. the following is the script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var date = new Date();

    var day = date.getDate();
    var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
    var year = date.getFullYear();

    if (month < 10) month = "0" + month;
    if (day < 10) day = "0" + day;

    var today = year + "-" + month + "-" + day;       
    $("#theDate").attr("value", today);
});
```

HTML

```
<input type="date" id="theDate">
```

Can i know is it possible to set the value to the model value like:

```
$("#theDate").attr("value","@Model.Date")
```

I tried it, but  it is not working. Can someone help me with this.

Comment: If you're using ASP.net there's no reason to do this in Javascript. If you're using ASP.NET MVC (as it looks like from your reference to `@Model`), you should tag it as such. And if so, `@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Date, new { type = "date" })` should work fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply this directly to the `input`, no javascript involved:

```
<input type="date" id="theDate" value='@Model.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")' />
```

Date must be in the format `yyyy-MM-dd`, hence the `ToString()` conversion. If you wish, you can continue to apply this with javascript:

```
$("#theDate").attr("value","@Model.Date.ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')");
```